# FileUpload control (UploadButton.PostedFile.FileName)

Tags: asp.net

Recently i developed a code on asp that requires to upload a file up to a server. 
As i found out from the web, in order to view the local file of a file it can be done by doing UploadButton.PostedFile.Filename.

```
string fileName = UploadButton.PostedFile.Filename;
```

This will show the whole local path(eg. C:\Documents and Settings\christopher.lim\Desktop\HelloWorld.txt).

This work fine if it is run the code on my desktop (where my PC is the server itself) but when i shifted the code over to a test server and tried it on my desktop(PC is the client), it only display my file name instead of the whole path.

Example:

```
string fileName = UploadButton.PostedFile.Filename;

Response.Write("FileName: " + fileName);
```

1) Local PC -> C:\Documents and Settings\christopher.lim\Desktop\HelloWorld.txt

2) Test Server -> HelloWorld.txt

P/S: Sorry if it's confusing because i am new to server client. Correct me if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filename.aspx)-

> The file name that the FileName property returns does not include the
>   path of the file on the client.

While it is true that on a local system you can get the complete path, but while you run it on a server it will only return the name of the file.

Also FYI the file upload control behaves differently in different browsers. In firefox you ill probably get only the file name and not the full path using fileupload.postedfile.filename and in IE the same thing may show you the full path.

However the path of the file uploaded from client system shouldn't matter as only the file name is more than enough, but if you still have the need try- `Path.GetFileName(filename)` [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx)

Comment: Thank you so much. Clearly explained. By the way, i tried out Path.GetFileName(filename), it will show the file name and not the path. But anyway, like you said, file name is more than enough